# Android - What is the event to override on phone close

Tags: android

I have an Xperia Mini Pro and I'm making a specific application.

I have a full screen activity with things moving around but when I close the phone (physically) it resets the positions of the stuff on screen.

Is there a method that I can override to prevent this, like "onPhoneClose" or something?

Answer (score 1):

This will trigger `onConfigurationChanged()` in your `Activity`; this is the callback that you need to override to intercept the event. However you will only receive this event if you declare that you care about the event in `AndroidManifest.xml` by setting `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"` in your `<activity>`.

Comment: That must be it, however it now gives me an error. If i dont call the parent method there is probably something i should do?

Comment: Nevermind that did the trick thanks, although i dont get it. If i just recall the parent method why doesnt it reset the state of the activity? And why did it DID reset before?

Comment: The default behavior is to restart the Activity, to force your app to reload within the context of the new config state. By declaring things this way, you tell Android that you are going to handle the change and that it does not need to reset.